# Line detection in tables on pdf using CV python

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I am trying to split a scanned pdf document into columns in order to perform OCR on it and extract the text in a structured fashion. here is a page of that document for example: https://ibb.co/ygC2sY7. I read on stack overflow that you can use CV to detect vertical lines and then split the columns so they can be processed with OCR one at a time. I am newer to python and haven't used CV, so I tried seeing what Chat GPT came up with, and the code it gave me overdetected lines and drew thousands of red lines that covered the entire page. I tried adjusting some of the parameters, but got the same result.

Here's the code I used

```
image = cv2.imread('1968 Plum Book-01.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(binary, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(closed, 1, np.pi / 180, 200)

line_image = image.copy()
for line in lines:
    rho, theta = line[0]
    if np.pi / 4 < theta < 3 * np.pi / 4:  # Filter vertical lines (45 to 135 degrees)
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a * rho
        y0 = b * rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))
        cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        
cv2.imshow('Processed Image with Vertical Lines', line_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Which part should I adjust in order to help python detect the vertical lines in the table on the page? they are clearly printed lines, so I think it won't be too difficult. sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#reading image
img = cv.imread('1968-Plum-Book-01.png',0)

#morphology to extract vertical lines
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(1,100))
thresh = cv.threshold(img,240,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
dilated = cv.dilate(thresh,kernel)

plt.imshow(dilated,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

If you want horizontal lines just invert the shape of the kernel.

After that it should be easy to use houghlines or findcountours to find the lines you want.

Edit: if you do the following erosion you will get only the lines. This should make it simple for you to split the columns.

```py
kernel2 = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(1,5000))
eroded = cv.erode(dilated,kernel2)
```